Replacing quadplex breaker for water heater, after removing HVAC system from quad breaker
I'm replacing my hvac system with mini splits.  My water heater is tied in to a quadplex breaker for the furnace.  Can I pull the quadplex breaker and run a 30 amp breaker for the water heater without rewiring the water heater?

You could leave the existing breaker as-is, unless there's something unmentioned that requires it to be removed or changed (for example, it's implied that the new mini splits will require new breakers and there may not be available slots for those, thus prompting your question). A photo of what you have and a more detailed description of what you need to accomplish will help us help you better.

The mini splits will be wired on separate 20 amp breakers.

The mini splits will be wired on separate 20 amp breakers.  The HVAC breakers and wiring will be completely removed from the panel to make room for the new breakers.

If you remove the HVAC that's on a quad with the water heater and replace the quad with a double for the water heater, you don't gain any panel spaces. Just leave the HVAC section of the quad off and then remove the wiring for the HVAC. Or expain what's really going on, as there's no benefit to this as described. [Edit] in a picture of the panel, perhaps.

Welcome, Doug. Please take the [tour], and put all information in your question post, not down here.

Will the new minisplits be on 120 V 1-pole or 240 V 2-pole breakers?
